# remove elements from `map` that are not in `set`

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmap, stl-algorithm

```
std::map<std::string, Obj> myMap;
std::set<std::string> mySet;
```

I want to remove those pairs from `myMap` which keys are not in `mySet`.

How do I do it? I found `std::remove_if` algorithm, but it seems to not be applicable here.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why `remove_if` is not applicable?

Comment: @juanchopanza: `remove_if` needs to rearrange the given sequence, something you cannot do with maps.

Comment: @KerrekSB I was hoping OP would put that kind of information in the question. Nevermind.

Comment: @Kerrek @juanchopanza SB Moreover, I cannot get it compiled. I suspect `remove_if` just cannot be applied to `std::map`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd start with this simple approach:

```
for (auto it = myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end(); )
{
    if (mySet.find(it->first) == mySet.end()) { myMap.erase(it++); }
    else                                      { ++it;              }
}
```

If you want something more efficient, you could iterate both containers in lockstep and do key-wise comparisons to take advantage of the compatible element order. On the other hand, the present algorithm works even on unordered containers, and given that your keys are strings, unordered containers may have a better performance anyway.

Comment: Is it really cool to remove elements from map while iterating over it? Wouldn't it result in undefined bahavior?

Comment: @Nick: it's cool... see e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase "Other references and iterators are not affected." - so the `it++` effectively advances `it` to the next iterator (which will be unaffected) before the `erase` kicks in.